# Parse data into in-memory-web-api in Angular 7

Tags: angular, xml-parsing, angular7, angular-in-memory-web-api

I'm looking to pull in data from an XML file and use that as the starting values for my in-memory web API in Angular 7:

My `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './app.database';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [HomeComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
            InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
        )
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The database is being created in a file called `app.database.ts`, found in `/src/app` (same place as `app.module.ts`

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    constructor() {}

    createDb() {
        return {
            products: []
        };
    }
}
```

I am currently stuck on how to implement the database. Specifically, I have the following questions:

- Which side will be the best place to put the database file. Assuming it's called `database.xml`?
- How do I retrieve the database inside the `InMemoryDataService` and subsequently create the in-memory database?

Any help provided is much appreciated